# Django CSRF token is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have an function in the custom.js file as follows :

```
function contactTraxio(fullname, telephone, email) {
    if (typeof(fullname)==='undefined') fullname = null;
    if (typeof(telephone)==='undefined') telephone = null;
    if (typeof(email)==='undefined') email = null;
    bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Limit reached",
        message: '<p class="text-main text-center">You have reached the limit of your calculations.</p>' +
                 '<p class="pad-btm mar-btm text-center">Upgrade your account by contacting us on +32 9 111 12 12 or filling in the form below.</p>' +
                 '<div class="row"> ' +
                    '<div class="col-md-12"> ' +
                        '<form class="" method="POST"> ' +

                            '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                                '<div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0"> ' +
                                    '<input id="contact-fullname" name="fullname" type="text" placeholder="Your fullname" class="form-control input-md" value="' + fullname + '"> ' +
                                    '<span class="help-block"><small></small></span> </div> ' +
                                '</div> ' +
                                '<div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right: 0"> ' +
                                    '<input id="contact-telephone" name="telephone" type="text" placeholder="Telephone" class="form-control input-md" value="' + telephone + '"> ' +
                                    '<span class="help-block"><small></small></span> </div> ' +
                                '</div> ' +
                                '<div class="col-md-12 pad-no-lr-md" style="margin-top: 7.5px;"> ' +
                                    '<input id="contact-email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email address" class="form-control input-md" value="' + email + '"> ' +
                                    '<span class="help-block"><small></small></span> </div> ' +
                                '</div> ' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</form> ' +
                    '</div>' +
                 '</div>',
        buttons: {
            success: {
                label: "Send",
                className: "btn-primary",
                callback: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: '/master/contact_traxio/',
                       data: {
                           fullname: $('#contact-fullname').val(),
                           telephone: $('#contact-telephone').val(),
                           email: $('#contact-email').val(),
                           csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                       },
                       success: function (data) {
                           debugger;
                       }
                    });


                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thus, I have an contact form in js. And I'm trying to send the form data to the django view with ajax.

I've added `csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'` to the data, but for some reason I get an error :

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /master/contact_traxio/
[03/Mar/2017 08:52:46] "POST /master/contact_traxio/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2502
```

The contact_traxio view is as follows :

```
@login_required
def contact_traxio(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Just test
        return HttpResponse('{} / {} / {}'.format(request.POST['fullname'], request.POST['telephone'], request.POST['email']))
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Sorry. Something went wrong.")
```

And the django template from where I call the `contactTraxio` function is as follows :

```
{% block page_content %}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var fullname = '{{ user.user.first_name }} {{ user.user.last_name }}';
            contactTraxio(fullname, '{{ user.telephone }}', '{{ user.user.email }}')
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Why is the csrf token isn't sent?

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Django template syntax in an external JS file. That can't work, because Django does not parse those files.

The documentation shows [exactly what you need to do](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax) to access the token from your JS; you should follow it.